# django admin form with predefined inlines

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

The problem is to have the inline models to have some of theirs fields preselected according to other model.

Let's make an example:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    DOC_TYPES = ((DC1, 'Doc type 1'), (DC2, 'Doc type 2'))
    doctype = model.CharField(choices=DOC_TYPES, default=DC1)

class OptionCategory(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField()

class Option(models.Model):
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document)
    option_category = models.ForeignKey(OptionCategory)
    some_data = models.CharField()
```

Assume that option is defined inline in document model admin.

`OptionCategory` is necessary - those may be added by admin - I'd like to have a creation form for Document with so many option models in inline forms as there is option categories. This can be achieved easily using extras in `Option` model admin. The questions are:

1. How to present inline fields each with different option category preselected?
2. How to change options dynamically (basing on `Document.doctype` after adding similar doctype field in `OptionCategory`) - preferably with ajax?

Comment: I'm not totally but you may achieve the behavior you want using [get_formsets_with_inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_formsets_with_inlines) method

Comment: Where is OptionType? Please, make a real example

Comment: `OptionType` == `OptionCategory`?

Comment: yes - I've corrected the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. How to present inline fields each with different option type preselected:

models.py

```
    class DocType(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name


    class Document(models.Model):
        doc_type = models.ForeignKey(DocType)
        some_data = models.CharField(max_length=255)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.some_data


    class OptionType(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        doc_type = models.ForeignKey(DocType)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name


    class Option(models.Model):
        document = models.ForeignKey(Document)
        option_type = models.ForeignKey(OptionType)
        some_data = models.CharField(max_length=255)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.some_data
```

admin.py

```
 class InlineOption(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Option
    extra = 3

    initial = [
        {'some_data': 'init_val1', 'option_type': 1},
        {'some_data': 'init_val2'},
    ]

    create_from_default = True

    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        initial = self.initial[:]

        class _Form(forms.ModelForm):
            form_initial = initial

            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                if len(self.form_initial) and not 'instance' in kwargs:
                    kwargs['initial'] = self.form_initial.pop(0)
                return super(_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.create_from_default:
            if request.method == 'GET':
                self.form = _Form
            else:
                self.form = forms.ModelForm
        else:
            self.form = _Form

        return super(InlineOption, self).get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)



class AdminDocument(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [InlineOption]
```

Comment: I should create `initial` according to existing Option(s) filtered by Document from `request` ?

Comment: you can filter by request, but main part - you need check request type, because form not saving with predefined values.

Comment: Sorry for delay, it works, but I had to create list of dictionaries in `initial` from OptionType...
But there is still problem. I've created Document instance and when I try to access it for changes it has another set of Options.